# Major Flood Events in Indonesia

Tags: geohazard

Seeking data regarding Major Flood Events in Indonesia during 2000 - 2010.

Could be GIS or just informational product.

[NASA's SEDAC (Socioeconomic Data and Applications Center) does this but only provides tallies and the data ends in 2003](http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/ndh-flood-hazard-frequency-distribution/maps)
I've also tried the [International Disaster Database](http://www.emdat.be/), however it does not have coverage good enough for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Quandl has these datasets: https://www.quandl.com/data/GEOCOMP?keyword=flood%20indonesia

Hope this helps.

[Disclosure: I work for Quandl]

Comment: Looks like they end at 2000?

Comment: @Ifyoudonotknow-justGIS Sorry! You're right. I apologize for that. I realize now you were looking for data for 2000-2010. I tried to double check the GEO-3 Data Compendium Website in case they had data after the year 2000 and unfortunately, it seems that 2000 is the most recent year: http://geocompendium.grid.unep.ch/data_sets/disasters/nat_disaster_ds.htm